# Error with R.string.default_web_client_id but build success

Tags: android, android-studio

The build of my project is succeeding, but `R.string.default_web_client_id` is marked as an error in Android Studio.

I checked that `values.xml` is well generated and that `R.java` file contains the value.

Android studio version is 3.3.1.

Comment: maybe try... getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)

Comment: Just a tip, my go to method for solving this class of issue: Click on the "Terminal" tab and type: "gradlew clean" followed by "gradlew assemble". It will show you much more clearly than the IDE what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart Android studio or if that desn't work try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart and click invalidate & restart . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It might be if you are using two different `string.xml` for two languages.

And if you add `default_web_client_id` string in only one `string.xml` then its showing marked as error in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to clean and re-build the project. 
If you have different string translations (more than one strings.xml resource), make sure you have the string translated in all languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Butterknife binding.

```
BindString(R.string.default_web_client_id)
String default_web_str;
```

Then user anywher you needed like as below:

```
textview.setText(default_web_str);
```